# Detener un proceso pasado cierto tiempo en Python

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, cv2

Me encuentro trabajando con un script que lee códigos de barra de una hoja.

Lo cierto es que en algunos casos el código de barra no se ve del todo "legible" como para que cv2 lo pueda interpretar lo cual hace que el script se demora bastante tiempo antes de desecharlo como y pasar al siguiente.

Lo que estoy buscando es algo similar al modulo SIGNAL que me permita tomar y limitar el tiempo que tarda en ejecutarse el proceso.

Dejo el código:

```
pdf = wi(filename=path_no_procesado + archivo, resolution=300)
            pdfImageTest = pdf.convert("png")
            i=1
            for img in pdfImageTest.sequence:
                page = wi(image = img)
                page.save(filename = path_pivot + 'img' + str(i)+".png")
                break
                
            image = cv2.imread(path_pivot + 'img1.png')
            time.sleep(3)

            barcodes = pyzbar.decode(image)

            for barcode in barcodes:
                (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect
                cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                barcodeData = barcode.data.decode("utf-8")
                barcodeType = barcode.type
                text = "{} ({})".format(barcodeData, barcodeType)
                cv2.putText(image, text, (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                print("[INFO] Found {} barcode: {}".format(barcodeType, barcodeData))
                nombre = barcodeData
                print(nombre)
            
            if barcodes == []:
                shutil.move(path_no_procesado + archivo, path_error + archivo)
                os.remove(path_pivot + 'img1.png')
            else:
                time.sleep(1)
                os.rename(path_no_procesado + archivo, path_procesado + str(nombre) + '.pdf')
                os.remove(path_pivot + 'img1.png')
```